# JS Passing by reference in a function

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
 var a = {};
 var b = {name:"Spork"};

 function connect(o1,o2){
    o1 = o2;
 };

 connect(a,b);

 console.log(a);
 console.log(b);
```

It prints: `{}{name:"Spork"}`

It should be: `{name:"Spork"}{name:"Spork"}`

Please tell me why at the end a doesn't point at b. If objects are passed by reference in a function, I thought that my function tells a to point at the same memory space as b.

Comment: In short, references themselves are passed by value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Passing by reference" is just an abstraction; you are actually passing *by value* the reference to an object in memory. So `o1` and `o2` are distinct variables containing the same references that `a` and `b` contain.

In simpler terms, `a` and `o1` are two different containers with the same contents. Same with `b` and `o2`.

Since `o1` and `o2` are independent of `a` an `b`, assigning one reference to the other does nothing outside of the function; all that does is overwrite the reference in `o1`, which means `o1` and `o2` will reference the same object..

What you want is to modify the *objects that the references point to*. In your case, you want to copy over all the properties from one object (namely, the object pointed to by `o2`) into another object (the object pointed to by `o1`).

Javascript offers a convenient way to do this using `Object.assign()`:

```
function connect(o1, o2){
    Object.assign(o1, o2);
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/purmou/kujxk4xw/)'s a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about visibility of your variables, see you are declaring `var a = {}; var b = {name:"Spork"};` outside of connect method ok and then you are passing them to the connect method, `o1 and o2` are local to `connect` method and whatever changes happens inside `connect` method will not be reflected outside of it, thatz why on printing them you are not empty value of `a`